# Make every version of "cease" the same - uppercase = lowercase = capitalized first letter = any letter capitalized

Tags: python, python-3.x, capitalization

I have the below code.

How do I make all cases of the word "cease" stop the program

Essentially I want cease = Cease = CEASE = ceaSe = cEasE etc

Any ideas?

```
Cities = []
UserCity = ''

while UserCity != 'cease':
    UserCity = input("Enter city = ")

    if UserCity != 'cease':
        Cities.append(UserCity)

print("\n" + 'Cities listed are: ')
for item in Cities:
    print(item)
```

Comment: lowercase or uppercase everything?

Comment: `while UserCity.lower()  != 'cease':` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do to save a lot of time is convert `UserCity` to lower case so you don't have to check every possible combination of cease.  This can easily be done as Joran Beasley said by:

```
while UserCity.lower() != "cease":
```

and for the other if statement it can be done by:

```
if UserCity.lower() != "cease":
```